# Constraining a shiny app input based on another input

Tags: r, shiny

I have a basic shiny app that evaluates **A** + **B**:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput(inputId = "A", label = "A", value = 5, step = 1),
    sliderInput(inputId = "B", label = "B", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5),
    textOutput(outputId = "value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText(paste0("A + B = ", input$A + input$B))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**A** is a `numericInput` value and **B** is a `sliderInput` value.

I want to constrain my app so that the maximum input value for **B** is always 2 * **A**. I, therefore, must change the hardcoded `max =` in `sliderInput` to something that can be dynamic. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: All of this information is on Shinys tutorial page already, besides there are loads of similar questions already asked on SO, just make sure you do your research, as it doesn't bring anything new to the community

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `renderUI()`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", label = "A", value = 5, step = 1),
  uiOutput("slider"),
  textOutput(outputId = "value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText(paste0("A + B = ", input$A + input$B))
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "B", label = "B", min = 0, max = 2*input$A, value = 5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: updateSliderInput is way faster though (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/06/speeding-up-r-shiny-the-definitive-guide/)

Answer (score 11):

You can call `updateSliderInput` to change the maximum value for B from within an `observe` which will be triggered whenever A changes:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", label = "A", value = 5, step = 1),
  sliderInput(inputId = "B", label = "B", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5),
  textOutput(outputId = "value")
)

# Notice the session argument to be passed to updateSliderInput
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$value <- renderText(paste0("A + B = ", input$A + input$B))
  observe(updateSliderInput(session, "B", max = input$A*2))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```